# How to align p-table and p-chart elements side by side

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a very little experience developing UI but I wanted to accomplish a task quickly where I have to put a p-table and p-chart elements side by side. I tried to use flex layout as well as float left and right as below but not getting the expected result. How can this be fixed?

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <div fxFlex="50%" class="floatLeft">
            <p-table [value]="summaryList" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px"
                     [resizableColumns]="true" [style]="{width:'500px'}">
                <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                    XXX Summary
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let col of summaryColumns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                            {{col.header}}
                            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-summaryList>
                    <tr>
                        <td *ngFor="let col of summaryColumns">
                            {{summaryList[col.field]}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 content-section implementation" fxFlex="50%" class="floatRight">
            <p-chart type="line" [data]="dailyData" title="XXX Chart" extender="overrideXAxis"></p-chart>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you try to put your code on stackblitz so that we can help you further

Comment: @davecar21 here it is. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krbhtp
I want the two components to fill a row and the chart be scrollable when it has lots of data horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this.

```html
<div class="container">
  <p-table [value]="summaryList" height="200" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="100px" [resizableColumns]="true" [style]="{width:'50%', float:'left'} ">
   <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    My Awesome Summary
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
     <th *ngFor="let col of summaryColumns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
      {{col.header}}
      <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
     </th>
    </tr>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-summaryList>
    <tr>
     <td *ngFor="let col of summaryColumns">
      {{summaryList[col.field]}}
     </td>
    </tr>
   </ng-template>
  </p-table>
  <p-chart height="250" [responsive]="false" type="bar" [data]="data" [options]="options" [style]="{width:'48%', float:'right'}"></p-chart>
 </div>
```

then add style to your component.css

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```